# PHP: Función propia de conexión a la base de datos no devuelve lo esperado

Tags: php, mysql, array, base-de-datos, funciones

A ver cómo explico esto porque es bastante farragoso: Dentro de un script que estoy desarrollando para facilitar la inserción de datos en una BBDD de recopilatorios musicales, se me ha ocurrido crear una función "conexion" (no tengo del todo claro que sea muy buena idea, pero como aprendizaje no está mal) para aquellas ocasiones en que he de extraer información (claves ajenas necesarias para completar las secuencias INSERT) de dicha BBDD.

La función aborda los cinco supuestos que se pueden dar en mi script, pero tengo problemas con uno en concreto: cuando necesito que me devuelva un parámetro de la BBDD dentro de un array asociativo que a su vez va dentro de un array escalar, tal que así:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [titulo_disco] => Free all angels [tipo] => LP [id_cancion] => 121 ) )
```

El parámetro que le reclamo a la BBDD en este supuesto es id_cancion; y el array escalar tendría 15 índices, del 0 al 14, tantos como canciones hay en el recopilatorio.

Mi problema es que no me devuelve un array escalar de tamaño 15 porque cada vez que la función le agrega un nuevo array asociativo, éste machaca al anterior, con lo cual el resultado final es un array escalar de tamaño 1 que sólo incluye el último array asociativo.

El código completo de la función es el siguiente:

```
function conexion($condicion, $sql1, $sql2, $atributo_bd1, $atributo_bd2, $array_asociativo, $array_escalar)
{
  require("conexion.php");

  if($condicion) $sql = $sql1;
  else $sql = $sql2;

  $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

  if(is_null($array_asociativo) and is_null($array_escalar)) while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados)) return utf8_encode($fila[$atributo_bd1]); #Devuelve valores individuales (ejemplo: id_lista)
  else #Si lo que se ha de devolver es un array
  {
    while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados))
    {
      if(!is_null($atributo_bd2)) #Si hay dos atributos, devuelve un array asociativo (2 valores) dentro de un array escalar
      {
        $$atributo_bd1 = utf8_encode($fila[$atributo_bd1]);
        $$atributo_bd2 = utf8_encode($fila[$atributo_bd2]);

        $array_asociativo = [$atributo_bd1 => $$atributo_bd1, $atributo_bd2 => $$atributo_bd2];

        if(!in_array($array_asociativo, $array_escalar)) array_push($array_escalar, $array_asociativo);
      }
      else #Si sólo hay un atributo
      {
        $$atributo_bd1 = utf8_encode($fila[$atributo_bd1]);

        if(is_null($array_escalar)) $array_asociativo[$atributo_bd1] = $$atributo_bd1; #Si no hay array escalar, devuelve un array asociativo (1 valor)
        else #Si hay array escalar
        {
          if(is_null($array_asociativo))
          {
            if(!in_array($$atributo_bd1, $array_escalar)) array_push($array_escalar, $$atributo_bd1); #Si no hay array asociativo, devuelve un array escalar (1 valor)
          } 
          else #Si hay ambos arrays
          {
            $array_asociativo[$atributo_bd1] = $$atributo_bd1;

            if(!in_array($array_asociativo, $array_escalar)) array_push($array_escalar, $array_asociativo); #Devuelve un array asociativo (1 valor) dentro de un array escalar
          }
        }
      }
    }

    if(is_null($array_escalar)) return $array_asociativo;
    else return $array_escalar;
  }
}
```

"conexion.php" simplemente hace la conexión con la BBDD.

El trozo de código en concreto que nos ocupa es éste:

```
else #Si hay ambos arrays
{
  $array_asociativo[$atributo_bd1] = $$atributo_bd1;

  if(!in_array($array_asociativo, $array_escalar)) array_push($array_escalar, $array_asociativo); #Devuelve un array asociativo (1 valor) dentro de un array escalar
}
```

A la función yo le proporciono un array asociativo de la forma:

```
Array ( [titulo_disco] => Free all angels [tipo] => LP )
```

A través de la llamada:

```
$condicion = strpos($cancion, "'");
$atributo_bd1 = "id_cancion";
$atributo_bd2 = null;
$sql1 = 'SELECT '.$atributo_bd1.' FROM canciones WHERE titulo_cancion = "'.$cancion.'"';
$sql2 = "SELECT $atributo_bd1 FROM canciones WHERE titulo_cancion = '$cancion'";
$array_asociativo = $trio;
$array_escalar = array();

$datos = conexion($condicion, $sql1, $sql2, $atributo_bd1, $atributo_bd2, $array_asociativo, $array_escalar);
```

Y ella le añade el id_cancion correspondiente y lo introduce dentro del array escalar, pero al repetir el proceso, en vez de ir haciendo crecer el array escalar hasta los 15 elementos como necesito, cada nuevo array asociativo machaca al anterior, y la función acaba devolviendo un array escalar con un solo array asociativo dentro, tal que así:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [titulo_disco] => Weezer [tipo] => LP [id_cancion] => 135 ) )
```

Sé que la pregunta es un infierno, así que infinitas gracias si alguien se toma la molestia de analizarla.

Comment: Sí, es un infierno: pero yo creo que, si nos das el contexto, igual podemos ayudarte. Necesitaríamos: la base de datos, la llamada a la función. Pues, entiendo que conexion.php únicamente te facilita $conexion, ¿no? Puedes compartirlo en GitHub y lo cogemos de ahí.

Comment: He añadido la llamada y la aclaración sobre conexion.php (que efectivamente sirve para lo que suponías); ¿qué necesitarías de la BBDD? La verdad es que no uso GitHub.

Comment: Si te parece, lo comentamos por este chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90845/php-y-mysql-arrays

Comment: Después de dos horas dándole vueltas con David -mil gracias, de verdad-, me he dado cuenta de que el problema es tan sencillo como cambiar "$array_escalar = array();" por "$array_escalar = $datos;"; de esta manera, ya no machaca el array cada vez que entra a la función...

Comment: La respuesta debe ir en el campo respuesta, con una explicacion clara del problema y la solucion. Tene en cuenta que futuros usuarios necesitan entender tu problema y tu solucion a ver si aplica para ellos tambien. Mira por favor [answer]